# axios and promises, array value not available but appears in console.log

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, es6-promise, axios

I have nested axios calls so using promises to build up my array of data that i will use for my application.

first call gets a list of headers or episodes.

second call takes the episode url recieved in the first to get additional data. I'm then adding properties to the array of data i want to use in my application. 
These are title and image_urls[0].

The third call then takes the image_urls[0] and does a call to retrieve that actual image. Now its in this call that when i console.log or do anything with the values added in the second call i get undefined, however if i console.log my complete array the values appear!

```
 console.log("sections", sections); // show all the data including 2nd call
 console.log("image url", item.url); // This shows
 console.log("image title", item.title); // This doesn't and don't know why
 console.log("image imageurls", item.imageurls); // This doesn't and don't know why
```

here is my code

```
import axios from 'axios';

let sections = new Array(),
    section = null,
    episodes = null;

const dataService =
axios
    .get('http://feature-code-test.skylark-cms.qa.aws.ostmodern.co.uk:8000/api/sets/coll_e8400ca3aebb4f70baf74a81aefd5a78/items/')
    .then((response) => {

    var data = response.data.objects;

    Promise.all(data.map(function (item) {
        let type = item.content_type.toLowerCase();

        if (type !== "episode") {
            if (section !== null) {
                section.episodes = episodes;
                sections.push(section);
            }
            section = new Object();
            episodes = new Array();
            section.header = item.heading;
        }

        if (type === "episode") {
            var episode = new Object();
            episode.url = item.content_url;
            episodes.push(episode)
        }
    })).then(function () {
        section.episodes = episodes;
        sections.push(section);

        Promise.all(sections.map(function (item) {
            Promise.all(item.episodes.map(function (item) {
                var url = `http://feature-code-test.skylark-cms.qa.aws.ostmodern.co.uk:8000${item.url}`
                axios
                    .get(url)
                    .then((response) => {
                    var data = response.data;

                item.title = data.title;
                item.imageurls = data.image_urls[0] !== undefined ? data.image_urls[0] : "";
            });

            }))
        })).then(function () {
            Promise.all(sections.map(function (item) {
                Promise.all(item.episodes.map(function (item) {
                    console.log("sections", sections);
                    console.log("image urr", item.url);
                    console.log("image title", item.title);
                    console.log("image imageurls", item.imageurls);
                }));
            }));
        });;
    })
})

export default dataService
```

Comment: You keep using `map()` but never return anything to those mapped arrays. `Promise.all([undefined,undefined])` is useless and won't wait for anything. Also not returning anything in the chained `then()`'s

Comment: @charlietfl Could you show me an example amending the code above?

Comment: @charlietfl the arrays I’m mapping I’m updating within the promise. Can you explain why the values appear when I console log the sections array but not when I do the item properties in the third call.

Comment: Will probably see it better yourself if you unwrap all the `map()` calls and store each in variable...then inspect what that array looks like before passing to `Promise.all()`. `map()` expects something `return`ed in the callback or you end up with an array where all elements are `undefined`

Comment: Simple example... `console.log([1,2,3,4].map(function(num){/*no return*/}))`

Comment: My array is not all undefined.  console.log("sections", sections); show the complete array. can you provide a more detailed example as an answer

Comment: you're using Promise's all wrong ... see the `axios.get(url)...` code in that first nested Promise.all nightmare? the result of that axios.get is what "fills in" your missing title and imageurls. but, since you're not RETURNING that promise chain, the outer Promise.all's have no promise to wait for, so the next overcomplicated nested Promise.all will execute "too early", because Promises **don't make asynchronous code synchronous**

Comment: @JaromandaX ok could you show me a better way to structure it in an answer.

Comment: Firstly, use Promises only where you need to - the quick and dirty rewrite of your code (I think) is https://jsfiddle.net/r7txrqo0/ - notice only a single Promise.all ... compared with 5 unnecessary Promise.all in your code? ... and using forEach, because .map is not required in your code at all - however, this is a quick and dirty rewrite

Comment: your code could be written https://jsfiddle.net/r7txrqo0/1/ - I still don't understand or like the first "loop" to be honest. And, in the end, `dataService` will be a Promise that resolves to `undefined`, same as your original code - because I can't tell what you want `dataService` to actually be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you, I think you have to spend a little time to study promises, map and reduce.

I got rid of axios and using fetch so it was possible to test it in the browser when on the site open an [api page](http://feature-code-test.skylark-cms.qa.aws.ostmodern.co.uk:8000/api/episodes/film_a5e1022dfd874e169fd6da6597d0cd0f/) and just run the code in the console (without the export line and replace const with var).

Please let me know if you need any help.

```
const base = "http://feature-code-test.skylark-cms.qa.aws.ostmodern.co.uk:8000";
const setEpisodeDetails = episode =>
  fetch(`${base}${episode.url}`)
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(
      data =>
        Object.assign(
          {}
          ,episode
          ,{
            title : data.title,
            imageurls : data.image_urls[0] || ""
          }
        )
    )
    .then(//fetch image url
      episode =>
        (episode.imageurls!=="")
          ? fetch(`${base}${episode.imageurls}`)
            .then(response=>response.json())
            .then(
              imageData=>
                Object.assign(
                  {},
                  episode,
                  {
                    image_content_url:imageData.url
                  }
                )
            )
          : episode
    );
const setAllEpisodeDetails = sections =>
  Promise.all(
    sections.map(
        section =>
          Promise.all(
            section.episodes.map(
              setEpisodeDetails
            )
          )
          .then(
            episodes =>
              Object.assign(
                {},
                section,
                {episodes}
              )
          )

    )
  );
const createSections = data =>
  data.reduce(
    (acc,item)=>{
      (item.content_type.toLowerCase()!=="episode")
        ? acc.push({header:item.heading,episodes:[]})
        : acc.slice(-1)[0].episodes.push({url:item.content_url})
      return acc
    },
    []
  );
const dataService =
  fetch(`${base}/api/sets/coll_e8400ca3aebb4f70baf74a81aefd5a78/items/`)
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(
      response =>
        setAllEpisodeDetails(createSections(response.objects))
    )
    .then(
      sections =>
          console.log(
            "sections", 
            JSON.stringify(sections,undefined,2)
          ) || //remove this console log if it works
          // (can remove the whole last then)
          //do not remove this it returns sections (unless you get rid of the whole then)
          sections
    );

//removed export, should log the result when done (or error)
```

Comment: Ok. Not understanding most of it so will do some research. Will try and add another call after setEpisodeDetails that loads the actual images

Comment: @Adam You can check if the output is correct if you open [this link](http://feature-code-test.skylark-cms.qa.aws.ostmodern.co.uk:8000/api/episodes/film_a5e1022dfd874e169fd6da6597d0cd0f/) in a modern browser (recent Chrome will do fine). Press F12 and in the console paste the code. Replace `export default dataService` with `dataService.then(result=>console.log(JSON.stringify(result,undefined,2)))`

Comment: Yes i can see it working. not sure how i extend it to have another request to the api after setEpisodeDetails to retrieve the actual image using the episode.imageurls . can you show me?

Comment: @Adam You mean get the image with fetch and store as base64? I'm not sure how to do that but can look it up tomorrow. You could try to write a function that takes a url and fetches the image, stores it as base64 and sets it to an img html element. You could just not download the image because you have the url so you can add the first part (http://www.barurl.com...) and just use that for your img src attribute. I'm not sure if your code runs on `http://feature-code-test.skylark-cms.qa.aws.ostmodern.co.uk:8000` if it doesn't the code may not work at all because I don't see allow-origin headers.

Comment: no not base64. Where it’s getting episode.imageurls the value is an api endpoint. From that endpoint one of the properties is the actual absolute image path. So I only need episode.imageurls temporary just to get the actual image after that call.

Comment: @Adam Ok, I get it. There is only one image in the set and I updated the code to add the url to the actual image.

Comment: yeah only one image for now. I’m going to add this into a react app and once working I’m thinking about adding redux to store state. All for learning purposes. Any course from Udemy you would recommend for JavaScript? I’ve spent far too long using jquery and building more classical multi page websites. Time to get more modern.

Comment: @Adam Redux is an event store, it stores events (called actions in Redux) and then calls a handler for this event. Best not to mutate actions or state (difficult in JS but as you can see in the code I wrote in the answer it's using `Object.assign` to return new object every time instead of mutating. I wrote a simple intro for my colleagues [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/redux-middleware/tree/master/basic) Only check out the basic one the other one sucks. You got any questions I'll be happy to answer them